# rviz_visual_tools ; Visualizing a plane in rviz (ROS C++)

Tags: ros

I get an error while following this instruction from README for visual tools:

```
In your class' constructor add: visual_tools_.reset(new rviz_visual_tools::RvizVisualTools("base_frame","/rviz_visual_markers")); Change the first parameter to the name of your robot's base frame
```

After looking into the `ros_param.yaml` file line: `robot_base_frame: base_link` I changed `base_frame` to `base_link`

I get an error in CMakeFiles:

```
CMakeFiles/listener.dir/src/listener.cpp.o: In function main': listener.cpp:(.text+0x16fe): undefined reference torviz_visual_tools::RvizVisualTools::RvizVisualTools(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >, ros::NodeHandle)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is a linker error. Looks like you're either not finding the package or it isn't getting added to your target link libraries. Can you provide your `CMakeLists.txt`?